# Foco na última linha da div com scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tenho uma div `chat-history` com atributo `overflow-y:scroll`.
Através do jQuery eu insiro informações no banco de dados e depois atualizo para exibir na div `chat-history`. Preciso que ao atualizar a div via requisição Ajax, a mesma fique com o foco na ultima linha da barra rolagem.

Segue trecho do código que faz a atualização da div logo após a inserção dos dados no banco.

```
function atualiza(){
  $.get(''+ url +'/chat-history', function(result){
  $('.chat-history').html(result);
})
 setTimeout('atualiza()', 3000);
 $('#message-to-send').val('');
 $('#sendMessage').attr("disabled", false);

 //neste momento a div chat-history que está com scroll deve ter seu foco na última linha
}
```

Tentei

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('.chat-history').offset().bottom }, 300);
```

Mas não tive o resultado esperado

Comment: Bem, se o scroll está no .chat-history, você deve chamar o animate no mesmo. Pode postar o código para que possamos lhe sugerir algo com mais precisão?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tem de passar o `scrollHeight` para o `scrollTop` do animate, e o seletor deve ser no elemento que irá sofrer a animação:

```
$('.chat-history').animate({ scrollTop: $('.chat-history')[0].scrollHeight }, 300);
```

[`scrollHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight): É um atributo *read-only* que retorna a altura de um conteúdo de elemento, includindo conteúdo não visíveis.

`scrollTop`: rola o scroll do elemento para posição definida, a partir do elemento passado via seletor.

Segue [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/SdUVd/68/).

Comment: Perfeito, mas pode explicar a `scrollTop ` e `scrollHeight`?

Comment: @Dagobe, editei a resposta :)